# How do I prevent users from rebooting terminal servers?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I just found out the other day that even non-admin users are able to reboot/shutdown our Windows Server 2012 R2 terminal server.  All they have to do is click the windows flag in the lower left, then click the power button and all the regular power options are available to them!

How do I go about restricting that permission?

Comment: Better, publish only the apps, not the full desktop ?

Comment: @yagmoth555  Not an option at this time unfortunately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, only administrators have the right to shut down (or reboot) a Windows server. 
 If this is not the case on your server, it is likely that you have existing group policy that changes the default configuration.

Start by checking the local security policy, in case the setting was changed locally.  Otherwise, you'll need to locate the GPO that is changing the "Shut down the system" setting and either correct it or add a new GPO to override it, perhaps only for these particular servers depending on your needs.

The relevant policy setting is called "Shut down the system" and can be found in Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Shut down the system.

Comment: Very helpful, found it, but it's grayed out.  Apparently a GPO is overriding.

Comment: The [gpresult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpresult) tool may be useful in identifying the relevant GPO.

Comment: Found a GPO eventually that was setup to let all non-admins shutdown any machine.  Not sure why it's there, must be to solve some kind of problem, probably with some specific machine someone was given special access.  Altered it to exclude our terminal servers as those I certainly don't want any of them shutting down and the *normal* servers they can't get into anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Use Group Policy.

Create and link a GPO to the OU where the RDSH computer accounts are.

Enable loopback policy processing in merge mode.

Configure the User Configuration setting in the image below.

[image]

Comment: That hides the GUI interface but will not prevent the users from shutting down or rebooting the system by other means.

Comment: Group Policy is definitely involved, but this option is not quite what I'm looking for.